# Can you precisely calculate $x^{\pi}$ (up to first 200 decimals) without a computer?

Tags: exponentiation, pi

I have recently learned how to calculate $a^b$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$.

I have noticed that the $a$ in fraction form will always be $a\cdot 10^n/10^n$ where $n$ is $a$’s decimal length. But if $a$ is a big number, it would be painful to write the exponent and to calculate the n-th root (in this case $10^{200}$'th root of $3.1415926\dots$).

Is there any easy/efficient way to calculate this? How might we best approximate $x^\pi$?

Btw I am a 5th grader so please try to explain it well (if possible)!

Thank you.

Comment: Have you ever heard of a Taylor series before? Whenever we want to calculate the first few hundred decimals of a function evaluated at a point, we usually just take a bunch of the terms out of the Taylor series. This is actually how your calculator approximates $\sin$ and $\cos$! Yes, you can do it by hand — although it’ll take you quite a while!

Comment: @ViktorGlombik Rational number1 and rational number 2(pi would convert to rational number(we only took first 200 decimals))

Comment: @JackCrawford no, i didn't, i receantly learned about mandelbrot set and i almost died, so my motivation was gone :P edit: what terms do I need, i am going on a trip soon, so i dont have 33 years to understand it.

Comment: @CppPythonDude If you want to learn about Taylor series, the prerequisite content you’ll have to learn first is just a bit of calculus. If you want to skip about 5 grades at school and be way better at math than your peers, I recommend checking out the Khan Academy playlist on calculus. If you know just a little bit about functions, I think you could probably follow along. After you know what a derivative is/how to differentiate, you could do this Taylor series thing by hand for any function you like!

Comment: Why would you wanna calculate something to 200 decimal places?

Comment: Search for Briggs construction of logarithm tables using square roots. The Encyclopedia Britannica says: "To construct this table Briggs, using about thirty places of decimals, extracted the square root of 10 fifty-four times, and thus found that the logarithm of 1.0000 0000 000012781 91493 20032 35 was 0.0000 0000 0000 05551 11512 31257 82702 ".

Comment: @kingW3 It's a pretty good party trick

Comment: @Ale your editing spree is pushing old questions onto the front page and pushing new questions off. Please limit yourself to two or three edits a day.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Uups, Sorry.. I've started editing old posts (really) trying to improve and I didn't see that I was doing it a lot! I'll take into account your advice (: (Unfortunately this is not the first time that I do so, I will be more careful with it)

Answer (score 1):

Bankers have an underestimate of compound interest gained, that will be helpful here. It says, add the percentages. If our percentage interest, goes above $2\times 10^{-198} \%=2\cdot 10^{-200}$ this method shows that the percentage interest gained after $10^{200}$ periods plus deposit, will exceed pi when written as a decimal. If estimated to 200 places past the decimal ( 201 significant figures) if we knock off that 201st significant figure we get a near perfect estimate to 200 digits of 1 . As to the title question (which isn't the same), You could, but you'd be wasting your time, if you know how to program it.

**Note:**

This estimate is very precise, but not very accurate.

Comment: "if you know how to program it". Did you see my name? lol

Comment: I don't care for names, I care for intellects.